# Tag Google Analytics y Tag Manager en la misma web

Tags: google-analytics

Tengo una web en la que tengo el UA de google analytics para medir métricas del sitio, recientemente agregue el container code de tag manager por requerimiento del cliente para hacer otras mediciones del sitio, este vincula dos cuentas más de google analytics. El problema ahora es que las métricas no están llegando a la propiedad de google analytics que tenia previamente en el sitio. Que debo hacer para que me sigan llegando datos a esta propiedad y conservar el tag manager.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: La alternativa, aunque no está aconsejada por el mismo Google Developers, es nombrar el objeto. Si en un Analytics envías unas peticiones, en otra puedes enviar eventos u otra HIT de google analytics (eventos, transacciones, social, timing, variables personalizadas, paginas vistas). **fuente** https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, tienes varias opciones:

1. Migrar tu etiqueta ala version (gtag.js)
2. Agregar dentro de la cuenta de GTM una etiqueta con la UA antigua que usabas y también deberás migrar tus eventos y retirar el tag de GA antiguo.

Sería ideal que colocaras detalles de tu portal para revisarlo.

Saludos,
JG